# how to disable/enable tinymce toolbar by command

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I need to disable/enable toolbar of tinymce editor by javascript. I am using

```
tinymce.get('description').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

code to disable the editor but it is not disabling the toolbar.

Please help.

Thanks
Avadhesh Mishra

Comment: Try this : tinymce.get('description').getBody().disabled=true;

Comment: @AmitAgrawal thanks for your reply. but it did not work.

Comment: please refer http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.ui.Toolbar.setDisabled

Comment: Try this, if you want disable first row then use as theme_advanced_buttons1: ''

Comment: Please provide a working fiddle so that we can help you better, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Prevent the mouse event from propagating to the buttons in the toolbar.

```
toolbarElement.addEventListener("click", function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Depending on which browsers you want to support, you could also use `pointer-events:none`

```
// disables
toolbarElement.style.pointerEvents = "none";
// enable
toolbarElement.style.pointerEvents = "all";
```

Reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

http://caniuse.com/pointer-events